# render_to_string getting TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple

Tags: python, django, django-views

In my function I am using `if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':` and when it is successful I am trying to return 2 HTML to be updated without refreshing the whole page but I am getting stuck with the error below;
`TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple` from traceback I found that the error is from the 2nd variable `render_to_string`
here is the views:

```
def change_status(request, id):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('active') == 'true':
            # .......do stuff
            context = {
                'active': ''
            }
            html = render_to_string('app/button.html', context,request=request)
            html2 = render_to_string('app/log_form.html', context,request=request) <-------- error here
            return JsonResponse({'form': html}, {'form2': html2})
        else:
            print("Fail")
    else:
        print("Fail")
```

***My question:***
How can I fix this error so that I can render_to_string 2 html pages and what exactly is the reason it is showing?

This is the my_custom_tags.py that is causing error

```
@register.simple_tag
def tuple_check(items, key, value):
    return (key, value) in items
```

I am using it to check if there are corresponding values in my tuple inside the django template.

here is the template:

```
    {% tuple_check all_logs b.order e.name as item_check_result %}

    {% if item_check_result %}
       do something
    {% else %}
       do something else
    {% endif %}
```

Here is the views that is creating the `all_logs`. The `log_order` is the integer and the `log_exercise` is string.

```
        all_logs=[]
        for i in active_session.log.values():
            new_name=i['log_order'],i['log_exercise']
            all_logs.append(new_name)
```

Comment: Please include traceback in your code and also the templates being rendered. You may cut out some details and provide a minimized version that reproduces the error.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule added the Traceback

Comment: @A_K The error is in the `tuple_check` function in `app/templatetags/my_custom_tags.py` please show this function and it's usage in the template

Comment: @IainShelvington added the tuple check

Comment: `all_logs` in your context appears to be a string but you are treating it like a collection of tuples, is that correct? Can you show the definition or a print of `all_logs`?

Comment: @IainShelvington the `all_logs` is something like this `(1, 'Technology')`

Comment: @IainShelvington I have added more context to the question regarding the `all_logs`